# How to scale brackets in Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying to draw a line with a closed interval indicated by square brackets super imposed on top of it. Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, tikz, amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->, thick] (0, 0) -- (15, 0);
\draw[[-], no marks] (1, 0) -- (14, 0);
\fill[black] (5,0) circle (0.75mm) node[below=2mm] {$p(x_1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my code]

As you can see, the arrowheads aren't very big at all. The brackets are especially bad. I've tried looking elsewhere but I seem to be unable to fix the brackets.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should enclose `[-]` in braces: `\draw[{[-]}, no marks]` otherwise you will get some errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Note that `arrows` is deprecated, use `arrows.meta` instead. And why are you using `no marks` here, isn't that `pgfplots` syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arrows` library got superseded by `arrows.meta`. Here, you can freely access all features, including the width, of arrow heads. (As pointed out by Phelype Oleinik, and as written in the manual, you need to enclose the arrow head by curly braces.) Below are <s>two</s>three examples. The second and third examples are due to Phelype and shows one way of introducing short cuts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[{Latex[width=4mm]}-{Latex[width=4mm]}, thick] (0, 0) -- (15, 0);
\draw[{Bracket[width=4mm]}-{Bracket[width=4mm]}] (1, 0) -- (14, 0);
\fill[black] (5,0) circle (0.75mm) node[below=2mm] {$p(x_1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Bracket[width=6mm,line width=1pt,length=1.5mm]}]
\draw[{Latex[width=4mm]}-{Latex[width=4mm]}, thick] (0, 0) -- (15, 0);
\draw[<->] (1, 0) -- (14, 0);
\fill[black] (5,0) circle (0.75mm) node[below=2mm] {$p(x_1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[>={Latex[width=4mm]},<->, thick] (0, 0) -- (15, 0);
\draw[>={Bracket[width=6mm,line width=1pt,length=1.5mm]},<->] (1, 0) -- (14, 0);
\fill[black] (5,0) circle (0.75mm) node[below=2mm] {$p(x_1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :) I'll intrude myself here and ask one thing: I was trying to do exactly that, but defining `[` and `]` as shortcuts for `Bracket[width=4mm]`. Something like `\tikzset{]/.style={Bracket[width=1cm]}}` so that OP's syntax can still be used. Can that be done?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I added a standard way to do that. You can also do that locally, of course, in the first line do it for the Latex head and then for the bracket. That is, you could also do `\draw[>={Latex[width=4mm]},<->, thick] (0, 0) -- (15, 0);
\draw[>={Bracket[width=6mm,line width=1pt,length=1.5mm]},<->] (1, 0) -- (14, 0);` in the last picture. I guess `[` might be complicated but I never tried.

Comment: Ooh, this only works for the `<` and `>` characters, right? I was trying with `[` :P

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, `[` has a special meaning. As you point out above, it needs to get shielded, so I do not dare to mess around with this character.